# Showing equality between a vector space and the direct sum of two subvector spaces.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathit{F} = \{ P \in \mathbb{K}[X] : P(1)=P(-1)=0 \}$
the exercise starts by asking to prove that $\mathit{F}$ is a sub-vector space of $\mathbb{K}[X]$, which easy to prove, but then also to show that $\mathbb{K}[X] = \mathit{F} \oplus \mathbb{K}_1[X]$.
Trivially, we have that $\mathit{F} \oplus \mathbb{K}_1[X] \subseteq \mathbb{K}[X]$ , but I'm stuck at showing $\mathbb{K}[X] \subseteq \mathit{F} \oplus \mathbb{K}_1[X]$.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for poiting it out.

Comment: Use `$F=\{ x\}$` for $F=\{ x\}$. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being in $F$ may be translated in terms of divisiblity by a polynomial. Use euclidean division in $\mathbf{K}\left[X\right]$ to conclude.